# Make Eclipse NOT run project on errors

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to make Eclipse (Helios SR2) NOT run your project on errors, instead of prompting for an answer or run anyway ?

Scenario:

In eclipse, I hit the Run button.  There are compilation errors.  Eclipse asks me if I would still like to continue with the run.  I have the options of "Yes" and "No".  I can also tick "Always run without asking".

In Eclipse Preferences, under Run/Debug > Launching there are radio buttons for "Continue launch if project contains errors", but they only give 2 options, "Always" or "Prompt".  Other sections on that page give the options "Never", but not this one.

Now.  I'd just like to never run if there are errors, without any prompt (a console message would be just perfect, but not required).  Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible.

But why would you want that?
IMHO the prompt was the best eclipse (or any other s/w for that matter) can do. If you hit run, then you hit run, and you want the file to run.

Is there any specific reason why you would want to hit the run button and the want the project *not* to run? It is very highly possible that you think you did not hit the run button and hot it again wondering what happened, rather than expecting that the project has errors.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  There is a very specific reason yes. If the project contains errors then i do **not** want it to run - ever.

I understand your concern about possible confusion regarding what happened.  This setting I'm looking for should of course not be the default behavior.
However, If I would set it so myself, along with a message in the console, then I wouldn't worry about confusion.

Comment: @Nivas don't you get burned by wondering why your latest changes aren't having any effect in the run?

Comment: @moodboom I understand your point, but if I choose "Run even with compilation issues", I should understand the risk (that not everything may be working as expected)

Comment: I think eclipse should add this option, that's the whole point of an IDE like eclipse is that it's customization, you should be able to customize it however YOU like.

Answer (score 9):

IMHO this seems like a very dangerous and error promoting behaviour (especially the "always run without asking" selection!)

If there are compiler errors, then I want the run attempt aborted so I can fix them, and if the code runs, then I want to be able to rely on it to (at least) be free from compiler errors...
Why on earth would I want to risk running code that contains compiler errors, and spend hours debugging weird behaviours in the execution, when the root of the problem is already known?

Wouldn't it be more natural to have "never" as default, and "promp" as an option?

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree. Running a project that contains a compilation error is indeed a very rare occurrence in my experience, making this dialog box a bit of a nuisance most of the time. A simple console message would suffice.

Comment: This answer hits the nail.  Anyone who uses "always run" has CERTAINLY been burned by wondering why their latest changes don't seem to be working.  This is Bad Design.  As a C++ guy I can't even fathom running if the build failed, it's absolutely bizarre.  

But in the answer, it sounds like you're saying the requested behavior in the question is a very dangerous idea.  In fact you are saying the opposite.  You are agreeing with the question but don't have an answer.  Seems like this should be a comment.  And I would love to see an answer.  Maybe time to submit an Eclipse request?

Answer (score 2):

Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching > Continue launch if project contains errors > Prompt
Voila!

Comment: The question was " ... **instead** of prompting for an answer ..."

Comment: It's the way I read the title.  It was the answer I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Prepend "Windows>".

Answer (score 1):

Use the Build button instead of the Run/Debug button.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. This is not possible today. The idea is that you often want to run the code even if there are errors in the code. The Eclipse Java Compiler can actually compile most classes, even if they contain errors...

Comment: I'm interested in any longer answers, if they say 'yes' somehow :)
Some people might want to run, even if there are errors - all depends on what you are doing.  They'll benefit from the "Always run even if errors" option.