# Eclipse c++ never run when build has errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

When programming in eclipse (c++), I would like to just hit f5 (run) and have the project I'm working on save, build and (if there are no errors) run. If there are errors I want it to show the problems window and stop.

This all works at the moment except for the part where it shouldn't run when there are errors.

Is there a way to make eclipse never run the project when there are errors? Perhaps with an addon?

EDIT: Forgot to mention the prompt... The prompt does show but I want it to not show at all. If you look at the preference window you'll see that there's no 'never' option, there is one for all the other options but not for the 'launch if project contains errors'.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the following one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518737/make-eclipse-not-run-project-on-errors

Answer (score 1):

By default, Eclipse CDT does not run code with build errors, but maybe you have checked the option *Always launch without asking* checkbox.

You should go to *Windows menu->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching->Continue launch if project contains errors* and check *Prompt* option instead of *Always*. Using this, Eclipse CDT will prompt you if errors exists during building or launch your binary if it has been compiled without errors.

Comment: Forgot to mention the prompt... The prompt does show but I want it to not show at all. If you look at the preference window you'll see that there's no 'never' option, there is one for all the other options but not for the 'launch if project contains errors'.